# Как сделать Data и Vuex реактивными?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Всем привет:
Есть такой код:

```js
<template>

  <div class="chart"
       v-bind:style="chartStyleObject">

  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default{

data () {
  return {

    chartStyleObject: {
      width: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.width,
      height: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.height,
      marginTop: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.marginTop,
      marginRight: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.marginRight,
      marginBottom: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.marginBottom,
      marginLeft: this.$store.state.chartStyleObject.marginLeft,
    },
  },
}
}
```

И такое хранилище:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
export const state = () => ({
  chartStyleObject: {
    height: '247px',
    width: '500px',
    marginTop: '15px',
    marginRight: '0px',
    marginBottom: '0px',
    marginLeft: '15px',
  },
});


export const mutations = {
    changeChartDraggableEventState (state, EventState) {
        state.chartDraggableEventState = EventState;
    },
    changeChartHeight (state, height) {
        state.chartStyleObject.height = height;
    },
    changeHeightWrapper (state, HeightWrapper) {
        state.chartStyleObject.HeightWrapper = HeightWrapper;
    },
    changeWidthWrapper (state, WidthWrapper) {
        state.chartStyleObject.WidthWrapper = WidthWrapper;
    },
    changeChartMarginLeft (state, MarginLeft) {
        state.chartStyleObject.marginLeft = MarginLeft;
    },
    changeChartMarginTop (state, MarginTop) {
        state.chartStyleObject.marginTop = MarginTop;
    },
};
```

Проблема:
Если я изменяю(в данном случае не важно каким(угодно) абстрактным способом) состояние хранилища через мутации - то св-ва хранилища изменяются корректно.
Но!
Свойства `data` на которое завязаны те же св-ва хранилища почему то не изменяется.
(Не смотря на то что св-ва хранилища изменены)
Вопрос:
Почему это происходит - если св-ва даты как и хранилища по идее должны быть реактивны? 
И какой подход является самым правильным в данном случае для решения данной задачи?
(писать напрямую св-ва хранилища в коде - кажется каким то очень громоздким решением.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть некоторые сложности с отслеживанием данных объекта. По этому, рекомендую вместо:

```
export const state = () => ({
  chartStyleObject: {
    height: '247px',
    width: '500px',
    marginTop: '15px',
    marginRight: '0px',
    marginBottom: '0px',
    marginLeft: '15px',
  },
});
```

сделать:

```
export const state = () => ({
  height: '247px',
  width: '500px',
  marginTop: '15px',
  marginRight: '0px',
  marginBottom: '0px',
  marginLeft: '15px'
});
```

И все сопутствующие изменения в `getters`, `actions`, `mutations`.

В компоненте же данные предложу выводить в посредством `computed` и `watch`, для случая, где необходим вывод большого количества `getters`, предлагаю использовать [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper), например так:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
         'height',
         'width',
         'marginTop',
         'marginRight',
         'marginBottom',
         'marginLeft'
    ])
  }
  // ...
}
```